# mysql query return boolean but I expect to return id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, subquery

This is my query:

```
select id
from inquiry
where id = (select min(id) from inquiry where (id > 108 AND is_deleted=N))
```

What is wrong in this query?
I'm expecting like in nested where id is compared to 108 and result will be greater than 108 but it returns boolean

calling function with parameters like
nextIdUserInquiry(108, $con, 'N');

and whole function body is below

```
function nextIdUserInquiry($inquiryId, $conn, $cond) 
  { 
    echo "in function"; 
    $qry="select id from inquiry where id = (select min(id) from inquiry where (id > $inquiryId AND is_deleted=$cond))"; 
    echo $qry; 
    $result = $conn->query($qry); 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
    echo $row["id"]; 
  }
```

and mysql error is that

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\besttour\admin\connect_db_test.php

Comment: What does the DB interface say when you execute the query, empty or error? If the PHP is relevant here please add the PHP usage.

Comment: `is_deleted=N` ... this will not run AFAIK, do you literally have this in your query?

Comment: How did you conclude result is Boolean it should result `ID` as per your query. Your query can be written as `select min(id) from inquiry where (id > 108 AND is_deleted=N)` between it will give the same result as your query unless you have some duplicate `Id's`.

Comment: calling function with parameters like nextIdUserInquiry(108, $con, 'N');          and whole function body is below                                                                                                                                                        function nextIdUserInquiry($inquiryId, $conn, $cond)
 {
  echo "in function";
  $qry="select id from inquiry where id = (select min(id) from inquiry where (id > $inquiryId AND is_deleted=$cond))";
  echo $qry;
  $result = $conn->query($qry);
  //echo $result;
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  echo $row["id"];
 }

Comment: and mysql error is that " Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\besttour\admin\connect_db_test.php "

Comment: @Naila - Add the above two comments to question.

Comment: @Naila what is the result when u echo the $qry?

Comment: I think there is some error in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the inner query returns a queryset, therefore you can't use `...where id=(select...` try instead `...where id in (select..`.

or even better try with the following:

```
select id
from inquiry 
where (id > 108 AND is_deleted=N)
order by id asc
limit 1
```

(tanks to P.Salmon)

Comment: can you write correct query here? thanks for helping

Comment: @TeacherLongLifeLearning top is sql server the myslq equivalent is limit (which needs to come after the order by clause)